# How to play Show "Framed/Dynamic" jpg url in SL4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, stream, jpeg

If i put this url:

http://186.215.144.12:81/cgi-bin/nph-zms?mode=jpeg&monitor=2&scale=100&maxfps=15&rand=1257471952"

On a tag img or in Browser Bar the image is rendered, im trying to use sl4 to get same result.

But formula URI->BitmapImage-> Image.Source don't work.

BitmapImage is forever downloading (Expected XD!!).

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your "image" is more like videostream and I believe Image.Source isn't going to help you here, because Image control expects image to be a finite number of bytes.

Try to use  `MediaElement` which is Silverlight way to display videos.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980132(v=vs.95).aspx